# Java generic method return list of any type extendends XXX

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a method that based on intpu String (not class) could return different lists of object extending XXX

So far I'm here, and I completly don't understand why this isn't working:

```
public <T extends XXX> List<T> getXXXList(String yyy) {
     switch (yyy) {
          case "test" :
               return getListOfTypeFFF();
      }
}
```

**EDIT**
here is what InteliJ is saying about this:
[image]

and you can trust me - Poi extends XXX

**EDIT 2**

```
public abstract class TranslationalEntity implemenst Serializable {

     private String tranlsation;
}

public class Poi extends TranslationalEntity {
     private String latLong;
}


public class Material extends TranslationalEntity {
     private String author;
}


public class News extends TranslationalEntity {
     private String time;
}
```

And for those type of entity I want to make one mthod that'll return right list:

```
public <T extends TranslationalEntity> List<T> getXXXList(String yyy) {
     switch (yyy) {
          case "poi" :
               return getListOfPoi();

          case "news" :
               return getListOfNews();
      }
return null;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

```
public List<Poi> getListOfPoi() {
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery("allPoi").getResultList();
}
```

Comment: How did you verify that it isn't working? Did you invoke it somehow? If yes, how? :)

Comment: plus complier error : `incompatible types: java.util.List<RDEWS.dataModel.Poi> cannot be converted to java.util.List<T>`

Comment: I guess your problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for those of us that don't want to just blindly trust you to include all relevant code.

Comment: @Tom yes and no. I dont try to add Poi to News List - I want one method that can return any child of T.

Comment: At what line in that code does it show the error? Where's code for `getListOfPoi()`?

Comment: I skipped method to get Poi's cause it's basic database query - just oneliner

Comment: other methods are same - oneliners - nothing to screw here

Comment: These methods are necessary, because we need to know their return types. If they are `List<Poi>` and `List<News>`, then it is exactly the problem I've linked.

Comment: *"I dont try to add Poi to News List"* This is not that question is about. I guess you want to return a List of child types, but your method "says" it returns a List of parent type. This doesn't work.

Comment: You can try `public List<? extends XXX> getXXXList(String yyy)` instead, but this may cause other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that you're trying to make compiler perform a decision that's not possible to do at compile time (statically):

```
String input = args[1];
List<Poi> result = getXXXList(input);
```

- should compiler allow this or not? You seem to think that this should be legal if the input is `"test"`, but compiler doesn't know the input.

Other way to look at it is - what should be the (static, compile-time) return type of the call `getXXXList(input)`?

- It cannot be `List<Poi>`, because you don't know what `input` contains
- It cannot be `List<XXX>`, because you cannot cast `List<Poi>` possibly used inside the method to `List<XXX>`
- It could be `List<? extends XXX>`, but the signature would have to be

  ```
  public List<? extends XXX> getXXXList(String yyy)
  ```

---

The `public <T> T foo()` signatures work well if the compiler can infer the return type's type parameter at compile time based on some input parameter's type, e.g.

```
public <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz)
```

but the compiler can only use the static information and cannot base its decisions on runtime values.

Comment: *"It cannot be `List<XXX>`"* is not quite right, because OP still can convert his `Poi` list to a `TranslationalEntity` list.

Comment: @Tom no they can not. `List<Poi>` cannot be cast to `List<XXX>`, because then I could do `List<XXX> myList = new ArrayList<Poi>; myList.add(new XXX());` and I would have a `XXX` in what is declared as a list of `Poi`s.

Comment: @JiriTousek and that's what I was missing - thank you Jiri for clearing that for me. I have to change signature of method to what you proposed `public List<? extends XXX> getXXXList(String yyy)` and it should not make any more troubles. Thank you once again.

Comment: @JiriTousek I wrote _convert_, not _cast_, please read carefully ;P. It is absolutely no problem to create a `List<Parent>` out of a `List<Sub>` if you iterate through the second list, cast each single item and insert it into the parent list.

Comment: @Tom right, I missed that. But it doesn't make sense when talking about what the return type of the method *as it is written now* could or could not be. It *could* be `Object` if rewritten so. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in wording my answer.

Comment: @Tom (after edit) - sure, you can do that. But I see no benefit to it compared to returning `List<? extends XXX>` unless you know for sure that all callers will need `List<XXX>` and not `List<? extends XXX>.

Comment: I just wanted to note, that it is possible, not that it makes more sense than another approach :P. If this has no purpose for someone, then he could also use a wildcard, like you said.